# Retrive Sast score of build using Azure devops api

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have set up a build pipeline to include Veracode scan and import results to true. once the build is successful I can see the Veracode score from the Veracode summary tab on the build page. Is there an API endpoint in azure DevOps API to retrieve this score to show in my web application?

Comment: I have tried a lot of build and build definition end points but nothing shows these details.

Comment: Used Veracode API as there are no option to use from azure DevOPs API